# JSON value update dynamically with process.env [node.js]

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

process.env.ENVIRONMENT = dev2

Input JSON:

```
{
   "base": {
       "product1" : "dev1.awesomeproduct1.com",
       "product2" : "dev1.awesomeproduct2.com"
   }
}
```

Output JSON:

Based on the process.env.ENVIRONMENT the product urls should be updated dynamically

```
{
    "base": {
         "product1" : "dev2.awesomeproduct1.com",
         "product2" : "dev2.awesomeproduct2.com"
     }
}
```

Comment: So, do you want to get particular product on the basis of `process.env.ENVIRONMENT` ?

Comment: No @MukeshSharma , based on process.env.ENVIRONEMNT argument, i need to launch the correct environment url for the product.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do I correctly understand that you want to replace the part of the domain names up to the dot with your `process.env.ENVIRONMENT` variable?

Then the following code should work:

```
for (key in myJSON.base) {
  myJSON.base[key] = myJSON.base[key].replace(/^[^.]+/, process.env.ENVIRONMENT);
}
```

Obviously, you will need to amend it if there are other fields than `product<n>`  in the `base` object, or if you need to do a more complex replacement.

Comment: Yes the process.env.ENVIRONMENT is a variable,
Yes there will be other fields other than 'product<n>' 

In the answer , we are iterating key and " /^[^.]+/," replaces the value?

Comment: We are iterating through all fields of the `base` field of the object you need to change (which I named `myJSON`). `replace` is a function that replace one string with another, and `/^[^.]+/` is a regular expression that catches all characters up to a dot (so that `dev1` is taken out of `dev1.awesomeproduct1.com`). You can see more on regular expressions here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions .

Comment: If you have fields other than `product` that you do need to change, you can use string `match` function with a regular expression: `if (key.match(/product\d+$/)) { ...do the replacement...} `. You can learn about JavaScript string functions and regular expressions in the JS docs (see the link above).